# Firebase Stripe Extension - adding custom claims to user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, jwt, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe with firebase and firestore using the Run Subscription Payments with Stripe extension. When a user subscribes to the service I need to be able to decode the JWT and see if they are subscribed or not through a custom claim.

[image]

[image]

The logs on the function show that it is invalidating the custom claim. I'm unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Once you have everything setup, the Stripe firebase extension should handle setting the custom claims automatically. Have you checked that your webhook handler has been configured correctly and is listening for all the necessary events? You can see instructions here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/ffccbe78c4cf458f36ea7d0057313f9012b50cd0/firestore-stripe-subscriptions/POSTINSTALL.md#configure-stripe-webhooks

Comment: The webhook is setup fine and is receiving the subscription created event, with the firebaseRole in the metadata in the request, and then storing it correctly in firestore. I've also added the signing secret to the extension. I have added the firebaseRole to both product and price so not sure what I am missing?

Comment: What are you seeing in the logs for the `ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-handleWebhookEvents` function? Can you include them in the original question and also show us what the Product looks like?

Comment: have included screenshot of the logs in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the logs you've provided, it looks like you have multiple subscriptions (sub_KBpVfFzNclrhaG and sub_KBpV10rxE6jkkH) that are both tied to the same user/customer. Subscription sub_KBpVfFzNclrhaG has a status of active or trialing, and so the custom claim was correctly added. However, subscription sub_KBpV10rxE6jkkH was created shortly afterwards (I assume with a status that wasn't active or trialing) which updated the user's custom claim again to null. You can confirm that this is happening by checking the statuses of both Subscriptions in your dashboard.

You need to make sure you have only one active/trialing Subscription per-customer, which would be something you check in your app logic. There's an example of how to check for active/trialing subscriptions for a customer here (https://github.com/stripe-samples/firebase-subscription-payments/blob/4cf116c163ba69f0f46bcc782e4162e0edf452a4/public/javascript/app.js#L121)